# Enable editing TextField only from the end of the text inside it

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield, string-formatting

I am creating a TextField for phone number.
But I have some trouble: I need to prevent users from editing it from any place, rather than the end of the string.

I tried to reset caret using "Touch up Inside", but it seems disabled for TextField.

Is there any way to limit caret possible positions?

The problem is that it ruins my code, which formats phone number. If you have any other good ways to format it without this problem (I need the string to look exactly like this: +7 (123) 456-78-90, not any other ways), I would appreciate your help.

```
private static var prev_phone: String = ""
@IBAction func phoneFieldTextChanged(_ sender: Any){
    if let phone = phone_field.text{
        if(phone.count <= 4){
            phone_field.text = "+7 ("
        }
        else{
            if phone.count > RegistrationViewController.prev_phone.count{
                if(phone.count == 7){
                    phone_field.text! += ") "
                }
                if(phone.count == 12){
                    phone_field.text! += "-"
                }
                if(phone.count == 15){
                    phone_field.text! += "-"
                }
                if(phone.count > 18){
                    phone_field.text = String(phone.prefix(18))
                }
            }
            if phone.count < RegistrationViewController.prev_phone.count{
                if(phone.count == 8){
                    phone_field.text! = String(phone.prefix(6))
                }
                if(phone.count == 12){
                    phone_field.text! = String(phone.prefix(11))
                }
                if(phone.count == 15){
                    phone_field.text! = String(phone.prefix(14))
                }
                if(phone.count > 18){
                    phone_field.text = String(phone.prefix(18))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        phone_field.text = "+7 ("
    }
    RegistrationViewController.prev_phone = phone_field.text!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this class to your text field to preventing users from editing it from any place.

```
class RestrictionTextField: UITextField {

    override func closestPosition(to point: CGPoint) -> UITextPosition? {
        let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument
        let end = self.position(from: beginning, offset: self.text?.count ?? 0)
        return end
    }
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.select(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.selectAll(_:)){
            return false
        }
        else {
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
}
```

For your text field purpose, you can use this simple solution.

```
let kPhonePattern = "+# (###) ###-##-##"
let kPhonePatternReplaceChar: Character = "#"

extension String {
    var digits: String {
        return String(filter(("0"..."9").contains))
    }
    
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String = kPhonePattern, replacmentCharacter: Character = kPhonePatternReplaceChar) -> String {
        var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
            guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
            let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
            let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
        }
        return pureNumber
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@IBAction func phoneFieldTextChanged(_ sender: UITextField){
    sender.text = sender.text?.applyPatternOnNumbers()
}
```

Comment: Wow, both solutions really do what they intended to do. Thank you very much for spending time for such dumb question)

Comment: String initialiser is not needed. `filter`applied on a string returns a string. `var digits: String { filter(("0"..."9").contains) }`. Btw why did you add that property and did not use it? `var pureNumber = digits`

Comment: @LeoDabus I added for, if you need to get a digit from the text field(with pattern) then it's useful. It only returns digits. And thanks for the filter correction.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, why use a UITextField ?
You you could for exemple create a custom keyboard made by yourself with only digit and delete button.
The user can only type a number or delete it. it's up to you to add the typed digit  to a formated string.